# Offline database in Android

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite

There must be a better way to manage string values than to have a bunch of strings in strings.xml file.

I am looking for database like solution, however I don`t want it to connect to a database on the internet. It is just that I need some advanced sorting and categorising to be done that  is all.

I am not very experienced with JAVA so pardon me if I just lack the knowledge.

EDIT: It would be nice that I could synchronize both database on the internet and on user`s smartphone.

Maybe effect of synchronization can be achieved by adding additional databases and sending out already modified data.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a SQLite database for your app. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: Is there a way  to update table later? I mean if I make a new app version with some addition to database will it be possible update or maybe these tables can be synchronised with Database on the internet?

Comment: Yes you can update the entries in an Sqlite database, but if you distribute it as an asset file you must copy it to the application working directory when the application is installed and access it from there since assets cannot be written to.

Comment: You can change the content of the database after you have inserted the first few values, either on app update either through code.

Comment: Also look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase, int, int)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to save them you could just use an array of strings or an array list if you have the user entering a bunch of strings  or need dynamic sizing

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are simpler alternatives to SQLite - you should at least consider some kind of ORM for Android. 
It'll let you to persist Java objects in a few lines of code instead of using `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, and marshalling data.

Consider [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/android) or something like that - it's rather large (~1M), though.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use SQLite for this? Remember that using a database connection for this (and only this) takes up resources that could be used elsewhere. If its strings that are only used as text (which never changes) in your program you are better of using the strings.xml. Not only is it faster, but it is also a Android Standard. Besides, if you decide one day into the future to translate your application to a different language I would guess it is much easier using the strings.xml file.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to add some data to the string like user feedback in form of ratings or comments.

Comment: You can use a Formatter for this instead, http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html